# grep with logic operators

Tags: grep

Is there a grep-like utility that will enable me to do grep searches with logic operators. I want to be able to nest and combine the logical constructs freely. For example, stuff like this should be possible:

```
grep (term1 && term2) || (term1 && (term3 xor term4)) *
```

I realize this can be done with vanilla grep and additional bash scripting, but my goal here is to avoid having to do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `awk`, as with `perl`, you'll have to wrap terms in `//`, but it can be done:

```
awk '(/term1/ && /term2/) || (/term1/ && xor(/term3/, /term4/))'
```

Note that `xor()` which is a non-standard GNU extension is a bitwise `xor`, not a logical one. It's fine here as those `/regex/` only ever return 0 or 1.

With other `awk`'s you can define a logical `xor()` as a function:

```
function xor(a, b) {
  return (a || b && ! (a && b))
}
```

Or

```
function xor(a, b) {
  return ((a && !b) || (b && !a))
}
```

Answer (score 63):

There are lot of ways to use `grep` with logical operators.

1. Using multiple `-e` options matches anything that matches any of the patterns, giving the *OR* operation.

   Example: `grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 filename`
2. In extended regular expressions (`grep -E`), you can use
   `|` to combine multiple patterns with the *OR* operation.

   Example:  `grep -E 'pattern1|pattern2' filename`
3. `grep -v` can simulate the *NOT* operation.
4. There is no *AND* operator in `grep`, but you can brute-force
   simulate *AND* by using multiple patterns with `|`.

   Example : `grep -E 'pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1' filename`

   The above example will match all the lines that contain both
   *pattern1* and *pattern2* in either order. This gets very ugly if there are more patterns to combine.

Comment: `-E` is not quite equivalent to `&&` due to the fact that it is order-sensitive

Comment: `grep foo | grep bar` is a more general way to do AND.

Comment: +1 for clearly explaining that there isn't a real "AND" operator, and that the best we can do is simulate a hack using an OR structure. This will of course get unwieldy with more than 3 terms, but for two terms it works well.

Comment: grep -c -e MATCH1 -e MATCH2 is great when you are interested in filename counts.

Answer (score 9):

You could use perl:

```
perl -wne 'print if (/term1/ && /term2/) || (/term1/ && (/term3/ xor /term4/))'
```

Where the [switches](https://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html/) are as follows:

```
-w turns on warnings
-n runs perl against each line of input (looping)
-e executes perl passed in the command line
```

Answer (score 4):

GNU grep allows perl regex, so we can do this to find lines containing both word1 and word2.

```
grep -P '^(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)' filename
```

(see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I use to chain `grep` commands to achieve a logical AND:

```
grep expr1 filename | grep expr2
```

I believe it is pretty straightforward, Unix-like and elegant.

---

Then you can combine (as @Tushi thoroughly explained) with the `-E` option for OR-ing and `-v` for negating.

Your specific example is pretty nasty and probably would benefit from some more powerful utility (see @muru's answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/term1/!d;/term2/b' -e '/term3/!d;/term4/d' -- *
```

I believe that accomplishes what you're trying to do. It `d`eletes from output any line which doesn't match `term1`, it `b`ranches out of the script *(and so autoprints)* any line that remains and that matches `term2`, and for lines that remain it deletes any which do not match `term3` and from those any that do match `term4`.

`sed` scripts are evaluated in order, and all tests are boolean, so any actions resulting from a test are going to directly affect the behavior of any following actions.