# grep AND feature from anywhere on the line

Tags: bash, grep

Is there any way for `grep` to have an AND feature? I mean something like this:

I have these lines:

```
I have this one line
I don't have this other line
I have this new line now
I don't have this other new line
This line is new
```

So I want for `grep` to find lines that contain BOTH the words "new" and "line", not only "new line". I know I can do this like this:

```bsh
grep new file | grep line
```

But that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to do this with one single `grep` command. This is because this script will let the user input the two terms, and one of the terms might be null, which then throws a `grep` error and breaks the script.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators

Answer (score 1):

If the second term is empty or unset, don't run the second `grep`:

```
grep -e "$term1" <file |
if [ -n "$term2" ]; then
    grep -e "$term2"
else
    cat
fi
```

This applies `grep` with the pattern in `$term1` to the file called `file` and then, depending on whether `$term2` is non-empty, applies a second `grep` to the result, or uses `cat` as a pass-through filter.

Note that this effectively implements "`term1` AND `term2`" except when `term2` is empty in which it degenerates into  just "`term1`".

---

If you'd rather not run `grep` at all and instead return an empty result when the second term is empty:

```
if [ -n "$term2" ]; then
    grep -e "$term1" <file | grep -e "$term2"
fi
```

This effectively implements "`term1` AND `term2`" and treats an empty  `term2` as "false".

The benefit of this is that it only relies on standard `grep` and that the two patterns are kept separate, which makes it easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: @Fólkvangr I've got too many ways to interpret that comment, could you please clarify?

Comment: @Fólkvangr How can one talk about an `OR` relationship when there's only one term?

Comment: @Fólkvangr Sure. If the wanted behaviour is to return _nothing_ if the second term is empty, then it's just a matter of `if [ -n "$term2" ]; then grep ... | grep ...; fi`, i.e. don't run any `grep` at all.  This may or may not be what the user wants.

Answer (score 0):

This will work (using GNU `grep`):

```
grep -P '(?<=new)\s(?=line)' file
```

Test:

```
$ cat > file
I have this one line
I don't have this other line
I have this new line now
I don't have this other new line
This line is new
^D

$ grep -P '(?<=new)\s(?=line)' file
I have this new line now
I don't have this other new line
```

Comment: Where is "This line is new" as it contains both patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Try what `man grep` calls "Concatenation" combined with "Alternation":

```
P1=line
P2=new
grep "$P1.*$P2\|$P2.*$P1" file
I have this new line now
I don't have this other new line
This line is new
```