# output mixed alphanumeric input with grep,pipe and cat

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, pipe, cat

I have a mixed wordlist as an input:

```
azert12345
a1z2e3r4t5
a1z2e3r455
```

The command line I have tried to execute:

```
cat file.txt | grep -E "[[:digit:]]{5}" --color
```

What do I want to accomplish:

Print only these words: "azert12345" and "a1z2e3r4t5", using `grep` with a pattern like I said before. Something like `grep -E "[[:digit:]]{5}"`.

It is easy to print words like "azert12345" using `grep -E "[[:alpha:]]{5}[[:digit:]]{5}"` with a maximum number of digits of 5 and a maximum number of alphabetical characters as 5, but the problem is: How am I going to print the mixed ones like this one a1z2e3r4t5?

The "a1z2e3r4t5" is just an example the mount of data i should deal with is so much biger

This problem is driving me to crazy for 3 days, and it is not a homework. I'll start learning again more about linux commands. I need some help.

Comment: IMHO this would be simpler in awk or perl, for the reasons outlined here: [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators)

Comment: is awk the only and the best choise i can make so what i want can come true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO this would be simpler in awk or perl, for the reasons outlined here: [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators) (in particular, that there is no natural `AND` operator in grep). For example

```
awk 'gsub(/[a-z]/,"&") == 5 && gsub(/[0-9]/,"&") == 5' file
```

or

```
perl -ne 'print if tr/[a-z]// == 5 && tr/[0-9]// == 5' file
```

will print lines containing exactly 5 of each of the character sets.

---

If you insist on grep, then something like this might work:

```
grep -xE '([^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*){5}' file | grep -xE '([^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*){5}'
```

Comment: thanks alot the grep command you gaved it works perfectly all i have to do now is to figure out how your magic works

Comment: What does `&` do?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv it re-substitutes the matched pattern - so that it's still there in the output

Answer (score 1):

Not using the *right tools*, [see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), but at least as an alternative:

```
while read i; do 
  foo=$(echo -n $i | sed 's/[a-z]//g' | wc -c) && bar=$(echo -n $i | sed 's/[0-9]//g' | wc -c)
  [[ $foo -eq 5 && $bar -eq 5 ]] && echo "$i  has five digits and five alphas" 
done < file
```

---

Delete the alphas, the remaning are the digits and count them. To be thorough, delete the digits, the remaining are the alphas, count them. Save each result in a variable:

```
foo=$(echo -n $i | sed 's/[a-z]//g' | wc -c) && bar=$(echo -n $i | sed 's/[0-9]//g' | wc -c)
```

---

If the variables are 5 characters long, then the string is five digits and five alphas:

```
[[ $foo -eq 5 && $bar -eq 5 ]] && echo "$i  has five digits and five alphas"
```

---

Output:

```
azert12345  has five digits and five alphas
a1z2e3r4t5  has five digits and five alphas
```

Is this logic faulty?

Comment: every time i trie to understand the meaning of this one ([^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*) i feel like my brain want to explode

Comment: @user11535592 Haha, I'm struggling with it right now. Ask steeldriver for clarification if he's kind to provide one.

Comment: he helped me alot by giving me a fish i am glad he did and i apreciate that but he didn't teach us how he did it i think we all have to make that engine works as always i hope you find your answers to and good luck