# How can I best search for 2 instances of 2 consecutive words on a line with grep or other search utility

Tags: grep

I have a log file that has 2 instances of 2 consecutive words on a line.

Example:

```
Process ID: 1034 Worker Process 4
```

I want to search for "**Process ID**" AND "**Worker Process**" on the same line.

The separate words "**Process**" or "**ID**" or "**Worker**" may also occur as separate words in the log that I do not want to find

Can you use `"` marks in a grep syntax.

Not sure how best to go about this.  Googled this alot.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: And I would like the search to find all the logs in the directory that have "Process ID" AND "Worker Process" on the same line in the logs.

Comment: Are they always in the same order? Anyhow, see if [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators) helps

Comment: Yes, they are always in the same order "Process ID"  and "Worker Process"

Comment: On the same line but not together?

Comment: they are on the same line, always together.

Comment: I tried :       awk '(/Process/ && /ID:/) && (/Worker/ && /Process/))'

Comment: But I get a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `"` inside a grep pattern. Specifically you can use

```
grep 'Process ID.*Worker Process' yourfile
```

to match the two quoted patterns where they occur in a single line separated by arbitrary text.

See [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators) for further discussion and alternate solutions.

Comment: I tried :  grep '"Process ID".*"Worker Process"' *     and I get no hits, when I should. the complete string that could be in the log is "Process ID: 1034 Worker Process 4" no quotes.

Comment: @OliversDad apologies - since you specifically mentioned using `"` marks in the pattern, I assumed you literally wanted to match `"Process ID"` and `"Worker Process"`- please see the amended answer **without** the quotes

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do, if I understand you correctly:

```
cd your_dir

grep -Ron "Process ID: [0-9]* Worker Process [0-9]*"
```

---

Go to the directory where the files are placed:

```
cd your_dir
```

---

Search recursively `-R` in the directory and retrieve only `o` the line you want,`n` will give you the line number.

---

Match the pattern `Process ID: [0-9]* Worker Process [0-9]*`

---

Given a file with content:

```
Process

Process ID: 1034 Worker Process 4

ID

Worker
```

Output:

```
a.txt:3:Process ID: 1034 Worker Process 4
c.txt:7:Process ID: 1034 Worker Process 4
b.txt:7:Process ID: 1034 Worker Process 4
```

Comment: Thank You SteelDriver and Guillermo Chamorro  !   grep -Ron "Process ID: [0-9]* Worker Process [0-9]*" seems to be what I need.  kinds regards.  Bob Perez

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you :)