# Using Grep to find two words on same line

Tags: regular-expression

I'm looking to use grep(or egrep) to find two words that are on the same line. ONT and MONDAY

```
Flight#   Airline  Depart  Arrive  Day
------------------------------------------
93104      TEAM     ONT     LAX   MONDAY
62876       GE      NYC     ONT  THURSDAY
30118      LOGI     ONT     PHX   FRIDAY
12033       F       LAX     PHX   MONDAY
40990      ACTI     PHX     ONT   MONDAY
92377       EA      ONT     PHX   SUNDAY
```

I've tried various commands but every line that has MONDAY or ONT are returned instead of line with flight #93104

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators)

Comment: ... although what I suspect you want to do is more like `awk '$3=="ONT" && $5=="MONDAY"'` i.e. match specific strings in specific columns

Answer (score 0):

Could be:

```
grep "ONT.*MONDAY" file
```

Comment: Given the data where the DOW is after the airport, this works; however, it wouldn't address the *general* question of "find two words that are on the same line" (where they could be in either order).

Comment: @JeffSchaller That's true, but if they could be in either order then the `awk` solution doesn't address the heneral question either because those strings might not be in those respective columns.

Comment: Use two greps, piping the output of the first one into the second: `grep ONT file | grep MONDAY`. Order does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the `ONT` word is to be found in the 3rd column, and the `MONDAY` word in the 5th:

```
$ awk '$3 == "ONT" && $5 == "MONDAY"' file
93104      TEAM     ONT     LAX   MONDAY
```

This relies on the values in the columns to not have embedded whitespaces.
The `awk` command above tests the values of columns 3 and 5 against the wanted words as strings and will output any line that passes the test.

To match `ONT` in either the 3rd or 4th column, and `MONDAY` in the 5th:

```
$ awk '($3 == "ONT" || $4 == "ONT") && $5 == "MONDAY"' file
93104      TEAM     ONT     LAX   MONDAY
40990      ACTI     PHX     ONT   MONDAY
```

If you used `grep`, you would not be certain that the two words matched *complete words* or in the *correct columns* (unless you made the regular expression overly complicated).