# finding multiple strings in a line

Tags: text-processing, grep, string

I'm brand new to Unix and am using CygWIN64 simulator. I have a huge number of text files (tens of thousands) that I need to search for specific strings. I have had success teaching myself to search using a single string, but I cannot figure out after several days of trying how to search for two strings.

My files reside in `c:/BF/data/`

My single string command is

```
grep -Rinw c:/BF/data/ -e 'string'
```

I have tried many example from online and cannot get any command to work with two strings (**an AND construction, not an OR construction**). If the two strings are present in a line I want to have that line show on the screen. Again, I have been able to do this with one string. The string might have a space in it - if that makes any difference. For example, one string might be 'Miami' and the other 'New York City'.

I have tried different `grep` commands, `awk` commands and nothing works.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators

Comment: Using the suggested page with examples my command is:

Answer (score 1):

To find 2 strings in a line:

Using GNU grep with Perl-compatible regexes:

```bsh
grep -RinP '^(?=.*\bMiami\b)(?=.*\bNew York City\b)' dir/
```

Perl regexes use `\b` as a word boundary.

With GNU awk:

```bsh
gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
    /\<Miami\>/ && /\<New York City\>/ {
        print FILENAME ":" NR ":" $0
    }
' file
```

Extended regexes use `\<` and `\>` as word boundaries.

However awk doesn't have an equivalent of `-R`. You could use find:

```bsh
find dir/ -type f -exec gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '...' '{}' +
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is available on @steeldriver linked post courtesy of @Campa.

```
grep -Rinw Miami . | grep -iw "new york city"
```

Just adding a few switches to get your recursive search and output

Using

```
Miami banana
Miami New York City
Miami banana
New York City banana
Miami banana
New York City Miami
```

if you have large numbers of files then avoiding the `P`erl with `grep` seems like a good idea

```
time grep -Rinw Miami . | grep -iw "new york city"
./file:2:Miami New York City
./file:6:New York City Miami

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.016s

time grep -RinwP Miami . | grep -iwP "new york city"
./file:2:Miami New York City
./file:6:New York City Miami

real    0m0.059s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.004s
```

There looks to be a `time` advantage of the above over @glennjackman with `P`erl

```
time grep -RinP '^(?=.*\bMiami\b)(?=.*\bNew York City\b)' .
./file:2:Miami New York City
./file:6:New York City Miami

real    0m0.069s
user    0m0.062s
sys     0m0.007s
```

And looping these 1,000 times over the same search `for i in {1..1000}; do ....; done` seems to confirm

@glennjackman `P`erl `grep`

```
real    0m49.276s
user    0m47.414s
sys     0m1.790s
```

@Campa `P`erl `grep`

```
real    0m42.841s
user    0m42.305s
sys     0m3.346s
```

@Campa simple `grep`

```
real    0m8.813s
user    0m8.837s
sys     0m3.081s
```

But the hands down winner over the 1,000 repetition sprint is @glennjackman `awk`

```
real    0m2.975s
user    0m2.259s
sys     0m0.772s
```