# How to search for lines that fulfill more than one criterion in Unix?

Tags: grep, search

I want to find the number of the lines that have both words/patterns "gene" and "+" in them. Is this possible to do this with grep?

Comment: Will the word `gene` always occur before `+` on the lines that you are interested in? Would the basic regular expression `gene.*+` be enough? Do you need to filter out lines that contain words like `genes` or `thegene` (i.e. where `gene` is just a substring and not its own word)? Can you show some example data?

Comment: Related: [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators)

Comment: You can just look for the first word and forward that list to another grep with second word: `grep gene | grep +`. That is a kind of and operator. You also need to consider all the question Kusalananda is asking.

Comment: @glennjackman I think the goal is to get number of lines and not line numbers.

Comment: I read the question more carefully after I commented: I agree.

Comment: As Glen Jackman pointed out, the question is about the number of lines. So `wc` should be used at the end to count the lines `grep gene | grep + | wc -l`.

Comment: @nobody or just make the 2nd grep `grep -c +` to count matching lines

Comment: @nobody there's no need for `wc`, you can use `grep -c`.

Comment: @Kusalananda the word gene always appears as "gene" and is its own word and it always comes before '+'.

Comment: Parnian, I gave you an answer assuming gff/gtf files. You might also be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with `grep`:

```
grep -c 'gene.*+' file
```

That will look for lines where the word `gene` appears first and as a separate word (the `\b` means "word-break") and then, on the same line, you also have `+` as a separate word. The `-c` flag tells `grep` to print the number of matching lines. If you also need to find cases where the `+` comes before `gene`, you can do:

```
grep -Ec '(gene.*\+)|(\+.*gene)' file
```

This, however, will also match things like `Eugene+Mary came for dinner` which is probably not what you want. Given the words you are looking for, I am guessing that you are looking at gff/gtf files, so you might want to do something more sophisticated and only look for `gene` in the third field of each line and `+` in the seventh, on lines that don't start with a `#` (the gff headers). If this is indeed what you need, you can do:

```
awk -F"\t" '!/^#/ && $3=="gene" && $7=="+"{c++}END{print c}'
```

Comment: For the Eugene case and grep, we can use word boundary markers: `grep -Ec '(\<gene\>.*\+)|(\+.*\<gene\>)' file`