# "grep string | grep string" with awk without pipe

Tags: bash, awk

Is there a way  to do:

```
output | grep "string1" | grep "string2"
```

**BUT with awk, WITHOUT PIPE?**

Something like:

```
output | awk '/string1/ | /string2/ {print $XY}'
```

Result should be subset of matches, if tha makes sense.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer here: [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177524/65304)

Comment: just a `|` missing : `awk '/string1/ || /string2/ {print $XY}' `

Comment: @Archemar that’s not quite the same though: `||` will match any line with either “string1” or “string2”, whereas the `grep`s only match lines with both (so `&&` in AWK).

Comment: my bad, I read too quickly once again ...

Comment: its supposed to mean column number e.g. $0, $1 etc.

Comment: _"Result should be subset of matches,"_ -- I guess the technical word is ["intersection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)), but it might be better to just spell out what you mean. :)

Comment: To be clear `grep "string1" | grep "string2"` does **not** grep for 2 strings, it greps for 2 regexps.You'd have to add `-F` to your grep commands to grep for 2 strings and then the awk answer you accepted would be wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default action with `awk` is to print, so the equivalent of

```
output | grep string1 | grep string2
```

is

```
output | awk '/string1/ && /string2/'
```

e.g.

```
$ cat tst
foo
bar
foobar
barfoo
foothisbarbaz
otherstuff

$ cat tst | awk '/foo/ && /bar/'
foobar
barfoo
foothisbarbaz
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because of the extra example/ proof

Comment: That is the equivalent of the pipeline the OP provided but if the OP actually wants to match 2 **strings** instead of 2 regexps then it'd be `awk 'index($0,"string1") && index($0,"string2")`

Answer (score 5):

If you want `awk` to find lines that match both `string1` *and* `string2`, in any order, use `&&`:

```
 output | awk '/string1/ && /string2/ {print $XY}'
```

If you want to match either `string1` or `string2` (or both), use `||`:

```
 output | awk '/string1/ || /string2/ {print $XY}'
```

Comment: Just to note, for anyone who stumbles upon this, what I exactly did was:
ps aux | awk ... to keep awk from showing in the result I had to do awk /[s]tring/. Its the same trick used for grep.

Comment: I think the `{print $XY}` thing is something like a placeholder that the OP thought would be useful/necessary. I believe it is better out of the answer since it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Quasímodo it makes perfect sense: it is a placeholder for "print field number N" and including it shows what the correct syntax would be, so it can easily be adapted by future users.